# ¿Cómo envío un archivo y un objeto a través de ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net

Ahora estoy llamando a este método desde ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CargarArchivo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, ArchivosHistoriaClinicaViewModel data)
{
    ///Codigo
}
```

Lo estoy llamando de la siguiente manera :

```
var formdata = new FormData($('#formArchivosResultados').get(0));

formdata.append('Título', 'Holi');
formdata.append('Detalle', 'Holi2');
formdata.append('AdmisionId', 123 );

$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Archivos/CargarArchivo",
                        data: formdata,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                        //Codigo
                        }
                    });
```

Si llama al método , el archivo(primer parámetro) lo obtengo bien pero el segundo solo me llega el campo título y lo demás nulo o en 0 ¿saben que puede ser? gracias , también añado el modelo del segundo parámetro por si algo

```
public class ArchivosViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Título")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
        public string Detalle { get; set; }

        public int IdPersona { get; set; }

        public long? AdmisionId { get; set; }

        public ArchivosViewModel()
        {
            Titulo = string.Empty;
            Detalle = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```